# Create new entities at runtime using NestJS + TypeORM

Tags: javascript, typescript, sequelize.js, nestjs, typeorm

Is there any way to dynamically create a new entity at runtime using NestJS + TypeORM (or any other ORM like Sequelize, MikroORM for that matter)? Use case is an application which allows users to create their own tables, update table structure as well as entering data.

Researching this issue always lead me to solutions which needed to restart the application which is not what I want.

Comment: Sequelize could do it for sure, I think others would be able too... sequelize.define creates a model, sequelize.models.ModelName.sync(); synchronises the DB, etc